# Copying File From Unix To Windows Clipboard

Tags: unix, vim, ssh, copy, clipboard

I want to copy a large file from a Unix server to the Windows clipboard using SSH.
How can this be done?

I can't install any third party application on the server
I tried various options like `%y+` But none of them working for me.

UPDATE :

Finally i used scp on windows cygwin and it worked like charm
Thanks

Comment: You are sure that this is the way to go? That simply (converting and) copying the file and getting it in the clipboard then is not an option?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - Sorry but not getting your question

Comment: Seeing as you already have SSH, chances are you have SFTP. It's easier to just copy the file/the contents of the file using a FTP program than relying on a shared clipboard.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question. putty contains an scp program (command line only IIRC). You can simply copy the file (as a file) to your Windows PC, open it there and copy its content to the clipboard with a Windows application.

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77757/copying-file-from-unix-to-windows-clipboard; please don't submit the identical question to multiple sites in parallel!

Comment: Closing since the crosspost has an accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PuTTY (or any Windows SSH client) just super copy it:

```
scp username@linuxMachineAddress&lt;linux directory path&gt; C:\Documents\filename.extension
```

For example:

```
pscp firdooze@192.160.1.233:/home/firdooze/helloWorld.txt C:\Documents\helloWorld.txt
```

More read [here](http://tech.firdooze.com/2009/11/12/how-to-copying-files-from-windows-to-linux-via-ssh-vice-versa/)

Answer (score 3):

Like the interactive session with your Unix server, you can also use `ssh` to execute a command and then quit. With `cat`, you can print the contents of files on the Unix server. Windows comes with the `clip` tool that captures output and places it in the clipboard. Voila:

```
ssh user@server cat /etc/passwd | clip
```

Comment: `clip` tool was exactly what I was looking for and still present in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you would do it with vim, vim could open remote file via scp directly.

try (on windows the command line could be different, but you got the idea)

```
vim scp://remoteuser@server.tld//path/to/your/large/file
```

**you have to have vim on your local machine (on your windows)**

then you could play with registers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install third party software, you have to do a `less <fileName>` and copy it out one page at a time. If you can install a different putty client (should be possible, it's a standalone executable, so you should be able to save it to your desktop) [There is a modified version of PuTTY that accomplishes this](http://ericmason.net/2010/04/putty-ssh-windows-clipboard-integration/).